# How to turn off standalone mode for Oracle ORDS

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

I have two servers. They are supposed to be identical. I also enabled the RESTful services on both servers. On one of the server, It gave me a `503 status error code` saying the password for `apex_pu` is invalid, expired or account is locked when I tried to use the sample API in oracle.example.hr.

```
https://hostname/ords/Schema Alias/hr/
```

However, the same sample API works fine on my other server.

I checked the apex_pu.xml file in `conf` folder under product folder and compared the two apex_pu.xml on both server. I found that the apex_pu.xml file on the failed one is missing `standalone = "no"`. I installed standalone mode before to look into some issues related to Oracle RESTful services. Then I left it like that ever since. I'm not sure if this is related to the issue that I'm currently encountering, but I'm trying to eliminate this difference by reverting it back to ORDS on Apache. I think this is the first step to troubleshoot my issue. Can anyone tell me how to revert this?

Commands that I used to enable standalone mode:

```
Java –jar ords.war configdir 

Java –jar ords.war (to start standalone oracle) 

Java –jar ords.war standalone (to start standalone oracle rest api)
```

failed one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

normal one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Comment: Stand alone mode won't have anything to do with user authentication in the database. Did you check the apex_public_user account in the database to see if the password was expired or the account was locked? If nothing else has changed on the ORDS server, then that's probably your best bet.

Comment: @pmdba sorry, I modified my question to clarify the issue.  Yes, I checked the password for apex_public_user and ords_public_user and they are open, not locked